# can't debug android projects in Eclipse (adt bundle)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging, adt

I can't debug any android projects on my PC. I am using the `adt bundle` version where in both Eclipse and SDK are bundled together. I tried almost all the solutions I found on here like restarting the PC (running Ubuntu), the android device and the `adb server`, adding `android:debuggable="true"` to the `manifest.xml` file, changing the debug port to `8601` but nothing helped. I have also tried debugging on another PC with the `adt bundle` and couldn't debug on it either. Is there something wrong with the adt bundle that prevents me from debugging or is there some setting in the SDK or Eclipse that I have missed out on?

Edit:

The error I get:

```
Launch error: Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection timed out.
```

Can anyone who has successfully debugged an android app using the `adt-bundle` comment on this post so I know it's possible?

Comment: You are putting breakpoints in right?

Comment: are you using emulator or device to debug?

Comment: i have put breakpoints and i am debugging on an actual device..though i have tried debugging on an emulator as well and it didn't work on the emulator either.

Comment: i can run the app on the android device, get screenshots, heap info and everything else except debug.

Comment: I am using adt bundle for almost 2 months now and able to debug app without any issues

Answer (score 3):

Did you turned developers options on in device? [see here](http://www.howtogeek.com/175151/8-things-you-can-do-in-androids-developer-options/)

also  [this may be useful](http://blog.enbake.com/debug-android-apk-device-eclipse/)

for your error connection timed out

go to Windows->Preferences->Android->DDMS. Change default port, apply, and restart Eclipse.

if this also does not work

do CTRL + ALT + DELETE and kill all adb.exe processes

Comment: i am on `ubuntu` and i have already tried setting the port to the default value and restarting the `adb server`.